# Change the number type of a CGAL mesh (lazy exact -> double)

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal

I have a *triangle* CGAL mesh with the exact kernel (`EK, EMesh3, EPoint3`) and I want to convert it to the same mesh with the inexact kernel (`K, Mesh3, Point3`). My solution consists in taking each vertex and each face of the exact mesh and adding them one by one to an empty inexact mesh. Is there a more straightforward way?

```
Mesh3 Convert(EMesh3 emesh) {
  const size_t nvertices = emesh.number_of_vertices();
  const size_t nedges    = emesh.number_of_edges();
  const size_t nfaces    = emesh.number_of_faces();
  Mesh3 mesh;
  mesh.reserve(nvertices, nedges, nfaces);
  for(EMesh3::Vertex_index vd : emesh.vertices()) {
    const EPoint3 vertex = emesh.point(vd);
    const double x = CGAL::to_double<EK::FT>(vertex.x());
    const double y = CGAL::to_double<EK::FT>(vertex.y());
    const double z = CGAL::to_double<EK::FT>(vertex.z());
    mesh.add_vertex(Point3(x, y ,z));
  }
  for(EMesh3::Face_index fd : emesh.faces()) {
    std::vector<int> face;
    for(EMesh3::Vertex_index vd : vertices_around_face(emesh.halfedge(fd), emesh)) {
      face.push_back(vd);
    }
    mesh.add_face(
      CGAL::SM_Vertex_index(face[0]), 
      CGAL::SM_Vertex_index(face[1]), 
      CGAL::SM_Vertex_index(face[2])
    );
  }
  return mesh;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either create a new mesh like you did but with the function [`copy_face_graph()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLHelperFct.html#ga2d3eb044bfe42eab566779ce32216c11) or you can use the `vertex_property_map()` parameter of PMP functions to have one mesh with different point map (exact and inexact).